# Fetching Data From a PHP Server Running MySQL

Tags: php, angularjs

I am learning angularJS and I am making a simple questions answer application using it.
So I have a controller which brings me the records of the ques from database and another controller which brings me answers/comments for that question from database. 
Problem- I am showing one record at a time using {{names[ques].question}} such that when ques is zero it will print the first question I have previous and next buttons to manage "ques" value. But I want only the comments for that ques to appear, instead my controller sends me all records.

Here is my html-

```
<div  ng-controller="customersCtrl"> 
<div class="well">
{{ names[ques].question }}
{{names[ques].id}}
</div>

  <span ng-controller="commentsCtrl">
  <div class="well" ng-repeat="x in comments">
  <span style="color:#3b5998;">{{x.name}}</span><br>
     <span ng-bind-html="x.solution | unsafe"></span> 
  </div>
  </span>  

</div>
```

And here is the script-

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function($scope, $http ) {
    $http.get("test.php")
    .success(function (response) {$scope.names = response.records;});
});
app.controller('commentsCtrl', function($scope, $http) {    
    $http.get("comment_view.php")
    .success(function (response) {$scope.comments = response.records;});
});
```

**All I want is that if there is a way I can pass the id of ques in comment_view.php so that comments appear according to the question being displayed.** 
PS: This is my first ques on stackoverflow I hope someone help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to accomplish this, you need to watch the question index (`ques`) value for changes, and when it changes, update the list of comments.

For example, in your `commentsCtrl`:

```
// watch for changes to the question index
$scope.$watch('ques', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  // check if it has actually changed
  if (newValue !== oldValue)
  {
    // request the comments for this particular question by
    // passing the question index back to the server
    $http.get('comment_view.php', { params: { ques: newValue } })
      .success(function(response) {
        $scope.comments = response.records;
      });
  }
});
```

Then, in your server, you would use the `ques` GET parameter to query for comments of that particular question.

---

Note that you may wish to better organize your code by placing the the `$http` logic into a reusable function, something like:

```
function loadCommentsForQuestion(questionIdx)
{
  $http.get('comment_view.php', { params: { ques: newValue } })
    .success(function(response) {
      $scope.comments = response.records;
    });
}
```

And then you can just call that function any time you want to load the comments for a particular question. For example, your `$watch()` call could be simplified to:

```
// watch for changes to the question index
$scope.$watch('ques', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  // check if it has actually changed
  if (newValue !== oldValue)
  {
    loadCommentsForQuestion(newValue);
  }
});
```

Comment: I have been trying since you posted this answer but $_GET['ques'] is not getting the value { ques: newValue } due to some reason I don't know.

Comment: From where do I call "loadCommentsForQuestion" ?
Can you please explain

Comment: I added a clarification to my answer for the `loadCommentsForQuestion` function. I also fixed my usage of `$http.get()`, which was missing the [`params` key](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage) (that's probably why it wasn't working for you). Please check again.